# Make it shorter by adding

Tags: word, wordplay

A five letter English word becomes shorter when 2 more letters are added to it.

1. What is the original word?
2. What are the 2 letters?

---

<sup>NOTE: I heard this puzzle from friends and don't claim my creativity</sup>

Comment: You should have asked smaller, the wording gives away the answer.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat: because _small_ is **not** a five-letter word with the same properties?

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat even `smaller` it self is an answer :P

Comment: why did i count small as being 4 letters, sorry it's been a long day. haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original five-letter English word is

> short

The two letters that are added to it are

> er

***Edit***: these two also work:

> Shore + tr
>  Sorer + ht

Answer (score 4):

I think it is

> short, and then add "er" to make it shorter!

Answer (score 2):

> **Shore**

becomes "shorter" when you add the letters

> **t** and **r**

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in your question and comment only

Its

> Small and Short

Add 2 more letters

> Smaller and Shorter

Answer (score -2):

The word is

> short + er = shorter.